# How can I create a list of dictionaries as value of another dictionary?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary

I am trying to create a list of dictionaries as a value of another dictionary.

I basically want to store data like this

```
userPrivileges ["foo"]["a"] = 4;
userPrivileges ["foo"]["b"] = 8;
userPrivileges ["foo"]["c"] = 16;
userPrivileges ["bar"]["a"] = 4;
```

Here is what I tried

```
Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, int>>> userPrivileges = new Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, int>>>();
```

To add or update a key in the dictionary list I use the following method

```
protected void AddOrUpdateUserPrivilege(string moduleName, string key, int value)
{
    if (!this.userPrivileges.ContainsKey(moduleName))
    {
        var entry = new Dictionary<string, int>(key, value);

        this.userPrivileges.Add(moduleName, entry);
    } 
    else
    {
        this.userPrivileges[moduleName][key] |= value;
    }

}
```

Here is a screenshot of the syntax errors
[image]

How can I add a new entry to the main directory? and how can I access/update the value of a dictionary in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries don't have a constructor to insert elements. You can use the collection initializer syntax:

```
var entry = new Dictionary<string, int> 
{
    { key, value }
};
```

Your other issues don't line up with the fact that you have a `Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, int>>>`, because you're using it as `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>`.

Since your code appears to make sense as the latter, I would suggest changing your definition to be:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> userPrivileges = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help with this. after updating the code with your suggestion it differently fixed the syntax errors. But when I run it I get the following error `An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The given key was not present in the dictionary.` the error is pointing at this line `this.userPrivileges[moduleName][key] |= value;`

Comment: @MikeA That's happening because `key` doesn't exist in your dictionary. You also need to check `if (userPrivileges[moduleName].ContainsKey(key))`

Comment: Right! Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @MikeA No worries mate :)